# The best way to connect the 7” touchscreen

Tags: pi-3, power, power-supply, display, touchscreen

I have a pi 3 model B+ and the official raspberry Pi PSU, and the official 7” touch screen. I’m running Raspbian with all the latest updates.

I have connected the display using a USB cable as documented on the raspberrypi.org site.

When I power up I get the underpowered lightning symbol.

What’s the right way to do this? Does using the jumper cables instead of the USB pass-through cable work more efficiently? Is there any other benefit to using them besides freeing up a port?

Answer (score 1):

I've got the power supply connected to the Raspberry and a USB from one of the four ports connected to the display. No lightning bolts with that set-up.

Before getting the TV HAT I used the jumper wires from pin#4 (5V) and pin#6 (GND) to the display. The TV HAT doesn't have pass through pins, so I switched to the USB cable.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a power adapter that can deliver 5-5.8V DC with at least 3A of current. Official Pi adaptors do this without any hassle.

Comment: I’m using the official Pi power adaptor : https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-universal-power-supply/ but it says it supplies 2.5A?

Comment: I'm not sure. I had a very similar problem when using the Pi with one of our analyser. I got myself a 3A official adaptor from Element14 and it solved our issues.